# How to put divider at particular position in an Android list view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I need to make a list view in which I want to have a divider at some position only not after every list item. I am using custom list view.

Is there any solution of this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can you this xml file in list adapter class like

```
ItemsAdapter ItemsAdapter = new ItemsAdapter(EnterpriseFertilisersScreen.this,
                R.layout.list, Constant.FERTILIZERMANAGERARRAY);
```

R.layout."below xml file " and user as further white color.

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"

    android:background="@color/list_bg" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/post"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/bite_image"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

If you have another issues, ask feel free..

Answer (score 2):

You can create Adapter for list, which will be place dividers as elements (via getView).
This is standart android approach

Answer (score 1):

If you have used Custom ListView to show your .you need to make position where you need to show different View from xml by condition .you should have to do this in `getView` Method.

Either you need to see how this example use divider using `CursorAdapter`.

Check this https://github.com/cyrilmottier/ListViewTipsAndTricks/blob/master/src/com/cyrilmottier/android/listviewtipsandtricks/SectionedListActivity.java

Answer (score 1):

you can add it to getview Methoid as follow :

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {     
    if(items.get(position).get("name").startsWith("-")){    
       View divider = mInflater.inflate(R.layout."yourlayout",null);
        return divider;         }
```

also, you must add item names starting with "-" where you want to add a divider.

Hope this helpful